# JEditorPane is removing CSS font styles

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jeditorpane

I am trying to get the JEditorPane to preserve any CSS font style. Unfortunately, it seems to be stripping it out altogether for paragraph tags (and other tags as well) and converting it to a font tag for the A tags.

Consider the following example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
public class EditorPaneTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String text = "<html><head></head><body><p style=\"padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 125%; font-family: Verdana;\">This is a test.</p>"
                + "<p><a href=\"http://www.google.com/\" style=\"font-size: 9px; margin-right: 10px; font-style: normal; font-family: Verdana;\">Google</a></p></body></html>";
        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/html", text);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(editorPane), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        text = editorPane.getText();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

This produces the following output for the p and a tags:

```
<p style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; line-height: 125%">
```

and

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" style="margin-right: 10px"><font size="9px" face="Verdana">Google</font></a>
```

As you can see, it preserves the padding and margin styles but strips out the font style for the paragraph tag and converts it to a font tag for the A tag.

Before `getText` is called, if you display it it will actually style the paragraph correctly.

How do I get it so that it will preserve the font attribute as is?

Comment: What styles does it define for the `BODY` element?  Why use both 'verdana' and 'Verdana' strings for the font?  Note that 1) an `<a name=..` is an anchor, while `<a href..` is just a link. 2) JEP has inherent problems with specifying size using `%` 3) Few developers consider JEP to be suitable for anything beyond carefully controlled and very limited HTML/CSS.  It seems you are trying to push it beyond the designed limits.

Comment: The above HTML is merely a sample to demonstrate the problem. My basic issue remains. It is removing the font styles for the p tag and converting it to a font tag for the a tag.

Comment: I am aware that JEditorPane has its limits, but it is clearly able to handle css font styles as it will display it using the specified font face. I just need to get it to leave the style alone.

Comment: @Avrom: "The above HTML is merely a sample to demonstrate the problem."  It is a very poor sample, and as a code snippet, it does not compile & therefore does not demonstrate anything.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: I've successfully done CSS styling in Java components. Note that Swing components will even work successfully with external style sheet specs! But now for my question: How do you know the style is being stripped out, i.e. how do you know what's inside the component? Are you just looking at what comes back when you do `getText()` after previously doing `setText()`? And does the *visible*, i.e. the displayed style change after performing a `getText()`?

Comment: @Andrew, I've updated the code. @Carl, the style does not change visibly on screen right after a call to getText but in the application that I am debugging, it is taking the returned text and saving it (thus changing it). You could then say I should use the original HTML text before the call to getText, but I cannot do this since the user may edit the text as well.

Comment: @Avrom: OK.. that is an intriguing mystery.  I'm sorry but I cannot say why JEP (mis)behaves that way or how to change the behavior.

Comment: Ok, I have been doing some investigating and the getText() method uses javax.swing.text.html.HtmlWriter to write out the html text to a buffer. I believe it is messing it up here. Another interesting find: That class has a writeCSS field that is always set to false and it has a method called convertToHTML40() that never gets called because of this. Let you know what else I find.

Comment: @Avrom. Looking at the same code as you in `HtmlWriter`.  That's crazy, obsolete code!  How about using reflection to set it to `true` and seeing what happens?

Comment: @BoffinbraiN, tried that, and while it is now calling convertToHTML40, there is a bug in that method! (Supposed to check for null and it doesn't.) Also tried copying over the entire class wholesale but can't do it since it depends on package access.

Comment: Damn. What a load of fail.  Well, all I can really suggest is to write your own document model that you apply to a `JTextArea`, to customize exactly what HTML it retained.  Or, you could have a simple text area for editing the HTML source directly, and use a read-only `JTextArea` as a preview pane.  If you want an excellent WYSIWYG HTML editor in Swing, it's just not going to happen - look elsewhere!

Comment: @BoffinbraiN, I believe I have fixed the issue by overriding/reimplementing key methods of HTMLWriter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

Figured out the issue is definitely in the `HTMLWriter` class. Unfortunately, they did not make it easy to override this class, but I beleive I have it.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Writer;
    import java.util.Enumeration;
    import java.util.Vector;
    import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
    import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
    import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
    import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
    import javax.swing.text.html.CSS;
    import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
    import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
    import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLWriter;

    public class FixedHTMLWriter extends HTMLWriter
    {
        private Vector                      tags                = new Vector(10);
        private Vector                      tagValues       = new Vector(10);
        private Vector                      tagsToRemove    = new Vector(10);
        private MutableAttributeSet convAttr            = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        private MutableAttributeSet oConvAttr       = new SimpleAttributeSet();

        public FixedHTMLWriter(Writer w, HTMLDocument doc, int pos, int len)
        {
            super(w, doc, pos, len);
        }

        AttributeSet convertToHTML(AttributeSet from, MutableAttributeSet to)
        {
            if (to == null)
            {
                to = convAttr;
            }
            to.removeAttributes(to);
            if (from != null)
            {
                Enumeration keys = from.getAttributeNames();
                String value = "";
                while (keys.hasMoreElements())
                {
                           Object key = keys.nextElement();
                    if (key instanceof CSS.Attribute)
                    {
                        value +=  key + ": " + from.getAttribute(key) + ";";
                        if (keys.hasMoreElements())
                            value += " ";
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        to.addAttribute(key, from.getAttribute(key));
                    }
                }
                if (value.length() > 0)
                {
                    to.addAttribute(HTML.Attribute.STYLE, value);
                }
            }
            return to;
        }

        @Override
        protected void closeOutUnwantedEmbeddedTags(AttributeSet attr) throws IOException
        {
            tagsToRemove.removeAllElements();
            // translate css attributes to html
            attr = convertToHTML(attr, null);
            HTML.Tag t;
            Object tValue;
            int firstIndex = -1;
            int size = tags.size();
            // First, find all the tags that need to be removed.
            for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                t = (HTML.Tag) tags.elementAt(i);
                tValue = tagValues.elementAt(i);
                if ((attr == null) || noMatchForTagInAttributes(attr, t, tValue))
                {
                    firstIndex = i;
                    tagsToRemove.addElement(t);
                }
            }
            if (firstIndex != -1)
            {
                // Then close them out.
                boolean removeAll = ((size - firstIndex) == tagsToRemove.size());
                for (int i = size - 1; i >= firstIndex; i--)
                {
                    t = (HTML.Tag) tags.elementAt(i);
                    if (removeAll || tagsToRemove.contains(t))
                    {
                        tags.removeElementAt(i);
                        tagValues.removeElementAt(i);
                    }
                    write('<');
                    write('/');
                    write(t.toString());
                    write('>');
                }
                // Have to output any tags after firstIndex that still remaing,
                // as we closed them out, but they should remain open.
                size = tags.size();
                for (int i = firstIndex; i < size; i++)
                {
                    t = (HTML.Tag) tags.elementAt(i);
                    write('<');
                    write(t.toString());
                    Object o = tagValues.elementAt(i);
                    if (o != null && o instanceof AttributeSet)
                    {
                        writeAttributes((AttributeSet) o);
                    }
                    write('>');
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean noMatchForTagInAttributes(AttributeSet attr, HTML.Tag t, Object tagValue)
        {
            if (attr != null && attr.isDefined(t))
            {
                Object newValue = attr.getAttribute(t);
                if ((tagValue == null) ? (newValue == null) : (newValue != null && tagValue.equals(newValue)))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void writeEmbeddedTags(AttributeSet attr) throws IOException
        {
            // translate css attributes to html
            attr = convertToHTML(attr, oConvAttr);
            Enumeration names = attr.getAttributeNames();
            while (names.hasMoreElements())
            {
                Object name = names.nextElement();
                if (name instanceof HTML.Tag)
                {
                    HTML.Tag tag = (HTML.Tag) name;
                    if (tag == HTML.Tag.FORM || tags.contains(tag))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    write('<');
                    write(tag.toString());
                    Object o = attr.getAttribute(tag);
                    if (o != null && o instanceof AttributeSet)
                    {
                        writeAttributes((AttributeSet) o);
                    }
                    write('>');
                    tags.addElement(tag);
                    tagValues.addElement(o);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void writeAttributes(AttributeSet attr) throws IOException
        {
            convAttr.removeAttributes(convAttr);
            convertToHTML(attr, convAttr);
            Enumeration names = convAttr.getAttributeNames();
            while (names.hasMoreElements())
            {
                Object name = names.nextElement();
                if (name instanceof HTML.Tag || name instanceof StyleConstants || name == HTML.Attribute.ENDTAG)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                write(" " + name + "=\"" + convAttr.getAttribute(name) + "\"");
            }
        }
    }
```

And you need to override the `HTMLEditorKit` class method `write` as follows:

```
    public void write(Writer out, Document doc, int pos, int len) throws IOException, BadLocationException
        {
            if (doc instanceof HTMLDocument)
            {
                FixedHTMLWriter w = new FixedHTMLWriter(out, (HTMLDocument) doc, pos, len);
                w.write();
            }
            else if (doc instanceof StyledDocument)
            {
                MinimalHTMLWriter w = new MinimalHTMLWriter(out, (StyledDocument) doc, pos, len);
                w.write();
            }
            else
            {
                super.write(out, doc, pos, len);
            }
        }
```

And set the overridden `HTMLEditorKit` on the `JEditorPane` using a call to `setEditorKit`.